# Change the artboard dimensions unit of measurement in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, measurement, units

In Adobe illustrator CC 2015 can I change the artboard dimensions unit of measurement? For example I buy a file online and the dimensions of the artboard are in px and I need it in mm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

File > Document Setup > Units

[image: Location of Units area]

Changing the value here will change the units used by your artboard(s).

Answer (score 7):

Control-Click or Right-click the **Rulers** at the edge of the window (View > Rulers > Show Rulers) and pick whatever measurement system you want.

[image]